# Foreach error in thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, thread-safety

I' have a timer that fires the following code. I need to show a form if the are a notice to show. The problem is that when thread is fired inside the thread and i set `ConfiguracioGlobal.DicNotices[kvp.Key].Shown = true;` the next run don't know that `.Shown` is true. When showing the form I get the following error: `Cross-thread operation not valid: Control '' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.` I think I have to use delegates but I have no idea :(

```
 System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(delegate
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Notice> kvp in GlobalConfiguration.DicNotices)
                    {
                        if (!kvp.Value.Shown && DateTime.Now.Hour == kvp.Value.HourIni.Hour && DateTime.Now.Minute == kvp.Value.HourIni.Minute)
                        {
                            GlobalConfiguration.DicNotices[kvp.Key].Shown = true;
                            FrmNotices frmPopup = new FrmNotices(kvp.Key);
                            frmPopup.Show();
                            Application.Run(frmPopup);
                        }                            
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error");
                }

            }));
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();
```

Any idea?
Thanks to all.

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to fire off a form on a non-UI thread.   I recommend you Invoke the main thread to generate the form instead. That should get rid of the exception, but it might not fix potential concurrency issues with the global Shown property.

Comment: Sorry - I doubt that you know what you are doing. What do you want to achieve and why do you do it so complicated?

Comment: JeffRson, I need to show messages in the new form and every 10 seconds check if there are new messages. I decidet to make it with a thread to avoid freezes in the main form.

Comment: @uoah Multiple UI threads makes it much, much, much harder to work with.  Not easier.  If you don't understand how to properly utilize an application using a single UI thread then you won't be able to understand enough to handle a multi-UI thread application.

Comment: ok then if it is so complicated I will try it without threads.. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to have multiple UI threads, and beyond that your second UI thread is neither an STA thread nor a foreground thread (both are a problem) and finally, based on your error, it appears that you're accessing controls from the improper UI thread.

Just don't do this.  Only use one UI thread and do all of your work from within that.

Don't start up a background thread to run these forms, show them all in the UI thread that you already have.  If you want to ensure that only one form is shown at a time use `ShowDialog`, and if you want multiple forms to be shown and active simultaneously then use `Show` instead.

Comment: As long as they are STA threads, in theory you can have as many as you want to.

Answer (score 0):

As long as they are STA threads, in theory you can have as many as you want to:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    var t = new Thread((s) =>
        {
            Application.Run(
                new Form
                {
                    Text = s.ToString()
                });
        });

    t.IsBackground = true;
    t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    t.Start(i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, at the end I've made it without threads, but I'll try your code.